# validate date format in python [with regex or any built in method]

Tags: python

I am having the python code that needs to validate the following date format:

**YYYYMMDD**

Above format does not contain any special characters like [:,-,/].

I have mentioned example like :

**20170922**

We need to validate that above is valid date format by following YYYYMMDD format.

if it's not, then it should raise some sort of error.

Comment: [RTFM](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)

Comment: Okay, you have our permission to do so.

Comment: Regex is not the right tool for this job. You can use regex to check if the input is exactly 8 digits, but any further validation should be done by a dedicated date/time library.

Comment: Yeah. I have seen some date/time methods like datetime.datetime() needs some date formats having special characters like YYYY-MM-DD or Y-M-D or Y/M/D. But in my case I dont want to use any special character in between to validate date format.

Comment: Is there any method to validate like that ?

Comment: Did you read the link wim included? You can construct your own format from the information there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use datetime for this (in python 2.7)

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = '20170808'

if len(date_string) == 8:
   datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y%m%d')
else:
   raise ValueError('date need to be in format YYYYMMDD ')
```

if you date is not valid than you get:

a ValueError Exception

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 0
```

Comment: Yeah it is working fine except one scenario like Instead of 20170909, I declared 201799 is also it is taking as correct format which is wrong case for me.

Comment: added an if len(date_string) == 8 for a case like 201799